# How to make a federated app using Intuit Partner Platform and get connected to it using .NET application?

Tags: c#, api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have created two apps in Intuit Partner Platform first using **QuickBooks API** and **Customer Account Data**. In the list of the apps I see **Integrated with QuickBooks Api** for an app created using **QuickBooks Api** and **Agg Cat** for an app created using **Customer Account Data**. I can see the credentials to connect to each of them.

But prior to me someone has created and app in which I can see Type as **Federated**. I am confused in how can I create or change the type of my apps to this one. Also on clicking the federated app unlike the apps I created I couldn't see the page containing credentials etc, instead I am seeing a page containing menus like Customize, Share, Recent etc.

Answer (score 4):

It is not advised to create any new federated apps. It will be decommissioned soon.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/06/20/decommissioning-federated-apps-focusing-on-the-future-with-quickbooks-api/

New Platform - Intuit Anywhere QB API
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi

FAQ - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq#Questions_for_Existing_IPP_Federated_Developers

Comment: Just to add, Intuit is not allowing new Federated applications to be created. There is a new programming model to be used. -Jarred